# How can I validate a particular fields in C# using List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i validate if storage location is equal to cost center or can return null when storage location is not equal to cost center or null?

```
public List<Lookup> RetrieveStorageLocations(string bu, string costCenter, ref DBResponseContext dbResponse)
{
    List<DbParameter> parameters = new List<DbParameter>();
    List<Lookup> storageLocations = new List<Lookup>();

    DbParameter p_storage_loc = this.MyAssetsSchemaUtil.CreateOracleUDTCollectionParam("p_storage_loc", "T_NIMA_ASSET_LKUP_OBJ_TBL", ParameterDirection.InputOutput, storageLocations);
    parameters.Add(p_storage_loc);

    DbParameter pStatus = this.MyAssetsSchemaUtil.CreateOutParam("p_status", NBRDBType.Int32, 30);
    parameters.Add(pStatus);

    DbParameter pStatusMessage = this.MyAssetsSchemaUtil.CreateOutParam("p_status_message", NBRDBType.String, 100);
    parameters.Add(pStatusMessage);

    DbParameter p_bu = this.MyAssetsSchemaUtil.CreateInParam<string>("p_bu", NBRDBType.String, 50, bu);
    parameters.Add(p_bu);

    DbParameter p_costcenter = this.MyAssetsSchemaUtil.CreateInParam<string>("p_costcenter", NBRDBType.String, 50, costCenter);
    parameters.Add(p_costcenter);

    this.MyAssetsSchemaUtil.ExecuteNonQuery("nima_asset_utl_pkg.get_storage_location_info", parameters);

    //Read the OUT parameters
    storageLocations = new List<Lookup>((Lookup[])(p_storage_loc.Value));
    dbResponse.Status = pStatus.Value.ToString();
    dbResponse.ErrorMessage = pStatusMessage.Value.ToString();

    return storageLocations;
}
```

Comment: can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the List.
By using a

```
foreach (var location in storageLocations) 
{
         // code here to check value
}
```

type of structure and check each location object against your target values.

I would give you a better code example,  sorry, kinda hard on my phone.

Is Someone out there that can give a fuller example? =)

---

Or maybe I'm being an idiot because it is late and I am tired.....